# View.getY() not returning correct position

Tags: android, view

I am programmatically adding views to a vertical linearlayout. All the Views are generated from the same XML. But if I call View.getY() on each of the views, it returns the same y value. Why does this happen? How can I make it return the correct Y value?

To be Inflated XML Code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/myView"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent">

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Preview of the to be Inflated XML: 
[image]

Java Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final LinearLayout host = ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.host)); //Linear Layout to hold the views, orientation = vertical

        //Creating the views and adding them to a list
        final ArrayList<MyObject> myObjects = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            myObjects.add(MyObject.createNewObject(this, host));
        }

        //Waiting for the screen to be drawn
        host.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                //get the Y position of each pink box
                for (MyObject m : myObjects) {
                    Log.v("MYOBJECT", "Y pos: " + String.valueOf(m.myPartView.getY()));
                }
                host.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            }
        });
    }
}

class MyObject {
    View myWholeView;
    View myPartView;

    private MyObject(View myWholeView, View myPartView) {
        this.myWholeView = myWholeView;
        this.myPartView = myPartView;
    }

    public static MyObject createNewObject(Context context, LinearLayout host) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout, host, true); //Inflating the XML Layout
        View other = v.findViewById(R.id.myView); //This is the little pink box 
        return new MyObject(v, other);
    }
}
```

I ran the code and the result was this:

Correctly Generated XML:

[image]

Log:

```
04-07 15:35:39.811 20695-20695/com.pythogen.tester V/MYOBJECT: Y pos: 150.0
04-07 15:35:39.811 20695-20695/com.pythogen.tester V/MYOBJECT: Y pos: 150.0
04-07 15:35:39.811 20695-20695/com.pythogen.tester V/MYOBJECT: Y pos: 150.0
```

Why are all the Y positions the same? I can I get them to be different?

Comment: Why do you expect the position to be different, is there any place in the code where you modify it ?

Comment: I expect the position to be different because I am calling View.getY() on three different views, each at a different Y position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value you get is relative to its parent, that's why you always get the same value. You can use `View.getLocationOnScreen()` if you want the position on screen.

Comment: According to the documentation:  `getY()  - The visual y position of this view, in pixels` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getY()

So naturally, I thought `getY()` would return the visual position, and `getTop()` returned the position relative to the parent. Thank you for the clarification.